# UITextView - Setting Border Color

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

In MonoTouch I am trying to set the border color, but the BorderColor is inaccessible due to its protection level and can't be changed.

```
public class BorderedUITextView:UITextView
{
    public BorderedUITextView (RectangleF Frame):base(Frame)
    {
        this.Layer.BorderColor (UIColor.Black);  ????????????
        this.Layer.BorderWidth = 1.3f;
        this.Layer.CornerRadius = 15f;
        this.ClipsToBounds = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "How is the border color set" - answered below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Layer`(if a `CoreAnimation.CALayer`) `BorderColor` is a property (not a method) as such it should be assigned like:

```
this.Layer.BorderColor = x;
```

Also it is a `CGColor` not an `UIColor`

```
this.Layer.BorderColor = new MonoTouch.CoreGraphics.CGColor (0.5f, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 10):

you can also get the CGColor from the UiColor

```
this.Layer.BorderColor  = UIColor.Black.CGColor;
```